# Heuristic algorithm in subarrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

**ORIGINAL PROBLEM:**

Given a set A={a1, . . . , an} and the matrix D of distances between the elements of A, we want to select the subset A*⊂ A of cardinal p with minimum diameter δ(A∗
) with δ(A∗) =max{d(a, a0) : a, a0 ∈ A∗}.
Write a python code that solve heuristically the particular case of n=8, p=4.

**WHAT I HAVE UNDERSTOOD:**

Given a matrix mxn (in this case 8x8) I am trying to look through a heuristic algorithm the max value of each sub-array of size 4x4, and store these values in a final matrix

For example:

Given the C matrix of euclidean distances 8x8:

What is the max value of a each possible sub-array 4x4?
and then store this max value in the final matrix mxn..

I have tried this but only returns one max value in the matrix.

```
# Python 3 Program to find the maximum 
# value in a matrix which contain 
# intersecting concentric submatrix 



MAXN = 64

# Return the maximum value in intersecting 
# concentric submatrix. 
def maxValue( n, m, x, y, a): 

c = [[0 for x in range(MAXN)] 
        for y in range(MAXN)] 

# For each center of concentric sub-matrix. 
for i in range( m): 

    # for each row 
    for p in range(n) : 

        # for each column 
        for q in range( n) : 

            # finding x distance. 
            dx = abs(p - x[i]) 

            # finding y distance. 
            dy = abs(q - y[i]) 

            # maximum of x distance and y distance 
            d = max(dx, dy) 

            # assigning the value. 
            c[p][q] += max(0, a[i] - d) 

# Finding the maximum value in 
# the formed matrix. 
res = 0
for i in range(n) : 
    for j in range(n) : 
        res = max(res, c[i][j]) 
return res 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 

n = 10
m = 2
x = [ 3, 7 ] 
y = [ 3, 7 ] 
a = [ 4, 3 ] 

print(maxValue(n, m, x, y, a))
```

Comment: Any attempt you have tried?

Comment: Hey, yes I have added the edit

Comment: I think a greedy algorithm would fit my problem, but I do not know how to implement it in sub-arrays,

Comment: max value of what? I don't understand what you try to optimise? How is the value defined for 1 matrix? Or how is it defined for 2?

Comment: hi, I just added the original problem to clarify.. maybe I have not understood well the purpose of the problem.

Comment: Looking at any possible 4x4 submatrix would be a full enumeration of the problem (with exponential time requirement) and not a heuristic approach. Instead, use a starting solution and try to improve it.